# Add class to the following tag. Concatenation

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

I've got problems with pointing at the LI tag that goes right after the A tag
Structure:

```
              <a id="2"></a><li>TextSimple</li>
$(function(){
     var str = '#2'
    $(str +' li').addClass('ownclass');
});
```

Check jsfiddle please http://jsfiddle.net/U2q6E/7/

Comment: `li` is not inside `a` tag, http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/U2q6E/9/

Comment: This is a **very** basic question. Sufficient information is provided in the always-useful [jQuery API documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/) I suggest you start there.

Comment: Now that makes senese. Solved. thankyou guys

Comment: This question is no longer a question because the OP put the solution in place of his question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the child selector where you should be using the adjacent sibling selector. Try this instead.

```
$(str +'+li').addClass('ownclass');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/U2q6E/11/)

Answer (score 0):

This code will work when you have

```
<a id="2"><li>TextSimple</li></a>
```

you dont have li inside a tag

> add + to your li if you want to select after

Answer (score 0):

You need a `+` in the selector, not just a space.

```
$(function(){
    var str = '#2'
    $(str +' + li').addClass('ownclass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
var str = "#2";
$(str).next().addClass('ownclass');
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U2q6E/13/